# How can I get out of low graphics mode on 12.04?

Tags: graphics, mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I cannot boot my laptop with 12.04 (or any older version) cos I keep getting the error message of "low graphics mode, " I click "OK" and then it gets stuck on a window giving me 4 options and I cannot do or choose anything, how can I fix this?

Comment: If you've installed 3rd-party drivers if you're on ATI, nVidia, etc GPU, then you'll need to disable them and try, let me know if that's a case, I'll guide you through how to remove them from your Ubuntu installation using LiveCD.

Comment: what graphics card do you have?

Comment: @Ashu I have Radeon graphic card. I am facing this same problem. Please help me in this. I am getting same error at same place

Answer (score 1):

I have recently received a similar issue with my System 76 Pangolin Performance laptop.  The folks at System 76 told me to run the following commands:

```
sudo chown lightdm:lightdm -R /var/lib/lightdm
sudo chown avahi-autoipd:avahi-autoipd -R /var/lib/avahi-autoipd
sudo chown colord:colord -R /var/lib/colord
```

These commands did the trick for me.

While I believe these commands/users might specific to System 76 it's worth checking the ownership of the directories (if they exist).  Also it would be useful if you edit your post to provide the company that makes your laptop and graphics card as a reference if this does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Click your name in the upper left hand corner, select "Switch User Account...", when logged out click on the little ubuntu symbol, and then select Unity 2D, and log back in.

Comment: If that doesn't work let me know.

Comment: thanks very much but it doesn't even get to the screen where the switch user account option is...

Comment: I did this, but it didn't change anything, but I just reinstalled my driver

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any idea what graphics card / hardware you're using? (Nvidia, ATI, or other)

I solved a [similar problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976217) by disabling the proprietary Nvidia driver. When you reach the login screen click the small circle with the ubuntu three friend logo to select a "unity 2D" session to login. from there use dash (super / windows key) to search for "driver". 
it's under "system settings > Additional drivers" . Then deactivate the driver in use.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't actually get to the log in screen, this happens just after I select the Lynux version I want to boot. Any other tips? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I tried that and it wont even let me go into the login screen. My graphics card is Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed and removed lightdm-kde-greeter and you want to go back to Unity try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity-greeter
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and select lightdm and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem because there was no space left on my root partition

To check disk utilisation,

```
df -h
```

Comment: I think it didn't answer the questions. Only check, not fix.

Comment: having similar issues... resolution seems to be clearing up disk space :)