# low-graphics mode after update to 13.10 and reinstallation of nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 13.10

I recently updated to 13.10 and it broke all my opencv stuff (impossible to compile or run previous programs that were ok on 13.04).

Cuda wasn't installed anymore, nor were the nvidia drivers.

So I tried to install them again (did it in 13.04). I tried all the suggestions here: [Has anyone successfully installed CUDA 5.5 on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380609/anyone-has-successfully-installed-cuda-5-5-on-ubuntu-13-10-64-bit)
That is, trying to install from:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.20.run
```

It didn't work but I could recover from the low graphics mode issue. After enabling the proper repository I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

It didn't work either. Finally

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates-dev
```

This got me totally stuck; I now can't get out of low-graphic mode.

I've checked and tried:

[NVIDIA driver problem after updating to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145195/nvidia-driver-problem-after-updating-to-12-04)

[How can I get out of low graphics mode on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137325/how-can-i-get-out-of-low-graphics-mode-on-12-04)

What else can I try?

Comment: Important note: I now get the splash screen normally, prompting me to input my password but after that remains a black screen with the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is what worked:

1. When I got stuck at the low-graphic mode window,  pressed CTRL+ALT+F1 to go to a terminal mode input
2. Log-in with user name and password
3. remove bumblebee:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee
   ```
4. reboot:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Reference:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197861